# JavaFX - How to refer to a cell's neighbor in tableview

Tags: button, javafx, tableview, tablerow, tablecell

I'm working on creating a table in JavaFX that contains editable properties. I want to be able to start editing, commit changes, and cancel with buttons that will be included in each row; however, I'm having some difficulty referring to the cell that I want to start editing. Ideally, I'd like to do something similar to this:

```
controller.buttonColumn.setCellFactory(p -> new TableCell<TableItem, String>(){
            @Override
            protected void updateItem(String s, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(s, empty);
                if (getTableRow().getItem()==null){
                    setGraphic(null);
                    return;
                }
                Button editButton = new Button("Edit");
                editButton.setOnAction(event -> {
                    getTableRow().getCell(1).startEdit();
                });
                setGraphic(editButton);

        });
```

This doesn't work though because TableRow does not have a method to access specific cells. Similarly, I could use a line like this:

getTableView().getEditingCell().cancelEdit();

for my cancel button, but the getEditingCell() method does not return a TableCell but a TablePosition, which does not have a method to access the corresponding cell.

tl;dr
I'm looking for a way to access a cell in TableView given it's neighbor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`TableView.edit(int row, TableColumn<S,?> column)` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TableView.html#edit-int-javafx.scene.control.TableColumn-):

```
controller.buttonColumn.setCellFactory(p -> new TableCell<TableItem, String>(){
    @Override
    protected void updateItem(String s, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(s, empty);
        if (getTableRow().getItem()==null){
            setGraphic(null);
            return;
        }
        Button editButton = new Button("Edit");
        editButton.setOnAction(event -> {
            getTableView().edit(getIndex(), someTableColumn);
        });
        setGraphic(editButton);
    }
});
```

where `someTableColumn` is the column containing the cell you want to start editing.

You can use the same method to cancel editing:

```
tableView.edit(-1, null);
```

Comment: I believe this is the answer I was looking for. It seems to be working well so far. Do you have any suggestions for a similar solution that could be used for the Commit Edit button?

Comment: @DarthRitis No: but you have more fundamental problems with `commitEdit`. Once the focus is moved away from a table cell (e.g. if the user clicks a button somewhere), the edit will be canceled by the cell's default implementation, so you won't be able to commit easily. Probably the easiest workaround for that is to "remember" which item is being edited and just directly update the model.

Comment: Canceling the edit upon losing focus is behavior that I'm ok with. Right now, my solution is to store each cell in a list when updateItem(...) is called and then loop through the list searching for the cell where cell.isEditing() is true and calling commitEdit(...) on that cell. This seems to work, I was just hoping for a more elegant solution. Let me know if you have any ideas, and thank you for all the help.

Comment: @DarthRitis Maybe I don't fully understand what you're trying to do. When do you want to call `commitEdit(...)`. I thought you were trying to do this when the user pressed some button that wasn't part of the cell whose edit was being committed.

Comment: I only want to commit the edit when the commit button is pushed. This button will be located in a cell that is in the same row as the editing cell. Any other action should either do nothing or cancel the edit

Comment: OK, but the problem is, by clicking on that button, the focus is lost from the cell, so editing is cancelled before you get to process the button click. Can't you just update the model directly? The button is in a cell, so you can get the row, and it seems you know which column is being edited, so I don't see why you wouldn't be able to just invoke a method directly on your model to update the data.

Comment: I created a new Cell class that extends TableCell exactly like the one in Example 12-11 from this link http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/table-view.htm. The only major change that I made is to add a listener to the focusedProperty of the row instead of the textfield and to cancelEdit() upon losing focus. In this way, losing cell focus does nothing as long as the focus remains on the row.